# Win8's Spell Checking API sends null as out param

Tags: c++, windows-8, com, atl, spell-checking

I am implementing a [Windows 8 Spell Checking COM service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869748.aspx) in C++ without ATL, but when Windows' msspellcheckinghost.exe calls my `ISpellCheckProviderFactory::SupportedLanguages()` it passes `nullptr` as the out param, to which I naturally return `E_POINTER` ... which results in a fail and an event log message of:

```
Failed instantiating third-party spellchecking provider: CLSID {...}, HRESULT 0x80004003.
```

When I make the factory class and DLL loader use ATL, then the host calls the function correctly. Which makes no sense, as the subsequent non-ATL `EnumString` implementation is used correctly. So why can ATL be required for the factory, but not after?

What makes matters worse, is that I have no idea how to attach the debugger to the host, as `msspellcheckinghost.exe` is undocumented so no clue what to pass to it.

The project source is available at https://github.com/TinoDidriksen/spellers/tree/master/win8 - prototypes are basically copied from Microsoft's own sample project, but I ripped the ATL parts out because I want the GUIDs to be loaded from a config file at runtime (that part works).

The same thing happens on 32bit OS+DLL, so has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Is the argument itself `nullptr` or the value it points to?

Comment: @PauloMadeira, the argument itself, which is the problem. I know that I have to assign to `*value`, but I can't do that when `value` itself is null.

Comment: Well, that's a complete fail whale, pretty unlikely anybody here can help you with that when you don't show us a small repro project..  Guessing at a wrong calling convention or the wrong interface pointer is rather a stretch.  No call stack either to deduce a guess.  Use a telephone, call Microsoft Support.

Comment: @HansPassant, edited to add source. Can't get a call stack as I don't know how to attach to or launch msspellcheckinghost.exe for debugging purposes. It's /? says nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [help of MS forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/0c404251-11a9-4ee7-b0df-aeb73b486327), the problem turned out to be that `ISpellCheckProviderFactory` is not an `IClassFactory`, and the DLL must return a proper `IClassFactory` that in turn can `CreateInstance()` the actual provider factory.